# issue loading properties file

Tags: java

I am having issue with loading

```
test.xml and test.properties
```

inside the same folder conf.

I have a myProject.jar inside dist folder and 
test.xml and test.properties inside conf folder.

To load xml, I am using

```
document = reader.read(new File("../conf/test.xml"));//its working
```

But I am having issue when loading properties file,
I am using

```
Class_name.class.getResourceAsStream("../conf/test.properties"),

   getResourceAsStream("conf/test.properties"),
   getResourceAsStream("/test.properties"),
   getResourceAsStream("test.properties"),
```

Nothing is working for properties file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try putting conf in the classpath and just doing getResourceAsStream("test.properties")

Comment: Agreed; you need to decide how you want to locate the file. The File constructor you're using is a full or relative path name for the file system, based on your current working directory. The #getResourceAsStream will locate a file in the classpath -- as Todd said, you'll need to include the 'conf' directory in the classpath in order to have access to it. Depending on how you want to ship your jar (with or without the configuration properties files) should give you some hints on which to choose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you take the file and load it using an `FileInputStream`

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
 properties.load(new FileInputStream(fileName));
```

The above code will take the properties file and load it into a properties object.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to differentiate between [Class.getResourceAsStream(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and [ClassLoader.getResouceAsStream(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). The call from Class is a relative path. So I imagine the following would work:

```
Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/conf/test.properties"),
```

... provided the parent of `conf/` is in the classpath.

If this doesn't work, look into how the classloaders are setup in your environment. You need to do a lookup from classloader that includes the conf directory.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the xml / properties ..what so ever file should be present root dir of the package

ex: com.abce.configuration --->readfile.java

xyz.xml
com
   -->abcd
          -->configuration
                         --> readfile.java